# How is stable_partition an adaptive algorithm?

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, quicksort

stable_partition is a function template present in algorithm header file of c++ STL.
I read that it is an adaptive algorithm and its time complexity is O(n*logn) or O(n) depending on some factors.Can someone explain me what are those factors and how the time complexity depends on those factors. Thank You !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on how much memory is available.

If you have enough memory, one way is to simply create a big enough buffer, insert the respective elements from the front and back and put it back into the original when done. This will take O(n) time.

If there isn't enough memory, [this page](http://csjobinterview.wordpress.com/2012/03/30/array-stable-partition/) mentions a O(n log n) in-place approach (there might be another approach as well) - if you want to rearrange `-` to the front and `+` to the back, you repeatedly find subarrays in the form `++++---` and rearrange it (stably) to `---++++` (which can be done with 3 reverses - reverse the whole subarray, then the negative part, then the positive part).

The physical checking for enough memory can simply be done by trying to allocate the memory and checking for failure. One way to do this is with a `new`, which can either throw an `std::bad_alloc` or return a null pointer, depending on the version used, if it fails to allocate the memory.

Comment: I disagree with the 3 reverses. If you do that, that is effectively std:reverse() for bidirectional iterators, and now the order of elements within the ++++'s or ----'s is inverted, which stable_partition promises not to do as part of its stability.
Instead what is needed is std::rotate() which preserves the order within the ++++'s and ----'s

Comment: @SJHowe The 3 reverses approach to swap negative and positive numbers would go like this: `[1, 2, 3, -1, -2, -3]` -> reverse all -> `[-3, -2, -1, 3, 2, 1]` -> reverse negative -> `[-1, -2, -3, 3, 2, 1]` -> reverse positive -> `[-1, -2, -3, 1, 2, 3]`. That's stable.

Comment: Bernhard: You are right. This reverse 3 times: I forgot that that is how rotate() is implemented for bidirectional iterators. I was mentally thinking of reverse() and if it had of been reverse() => it would not have worked. A mental aberration of mine. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

There are **2 implementations**.

1. "slower" `O(n*logn)` implementation
2. "faster" `O(n)` implementation

The **fast** implementation however needs to **use a lot of memory**, which may not be available. So the `stable_partition` asks the operating system if there is enough memory available and then chooses between the two implementations.

Here is an example from the **gcc 4.8.1 implementation** with some of my comments:

```
template<typename _ForwardIterator, typename _Predicate>
    _ForwardIterator
    stable_partition(_ForwardIterator __first, _ForwardIterator __last,
             _Predicate __pred)
    {
       ...
       ...

       /// Try to allocate enough memory for the faster algorithm
      _Temporary_buffer<_ForwardIterator, _ValueType> __buf(__first, __last);

    if (__buf.size() > 0)  /// If there is enough memory
      return
        std::__stable_partition_adaptive(__first, __last, __pred,
                      _DistanceType(__buf.requested_size()),
                      __buf.begin(),
                      _DistanceType(__buf.size()));
    else  /// If there is not enough memory
      return
        std::__inplace_stable_partition(__first, __pred,
                     _DistanceType(__buf.requested_size()));
    }
```

here `std::__stable_partition_adaptive` is the fast algorithm and `std::__inplace_stable_partition` is the slow algorithm.

Comment: Do you mind to give more details about std::__inplace_stable_partition implementation?

Comment: @JunGuo It is a recursive algorithm remotely similar to mergesort. You can find the definition in header `<stl_algo.h>` if you are using gcc.

Comment: It divides the range into 2 and recursively calls itself to do the stable_partition recording the return iterator. Afterwards, if you think about it, you now have partitioned the elements into 4 according to the predicate . You have T T T ... T F F F ... F T T T ... T F F F ... F according to boolean type. Use rotate() to move the 2nd and 3rd block into place, so that the final form resembles T... T F ... F according to boolean type. The recursion stops when you have 1-element (and you need to return the correct position according to predicate value) or 2-elements (swap if wrong order)

Answer (score 2):

See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_partition) :

> Exactly last-first applications of the predicate and at most
>   (last-first)*log(last-first) swaps if there is insufficient memory or
>   linear number of swaps if sufficient memory is available.

Comment: i was asking the explanation for the statement you wrote.By the way thanks for trying.

Comment: There is nothing more to say. The C++ standard do not provide more details. The factor to pick an O(NlogN) or O(N) algorithm depends on the availability of some additional memory, but their is no way to know the exact predicate as implementation details is in the hands of the compiler provider.