# stable_partition on forward iterators

Tags: c++, stl

**1.**
In the current standard draft the specification of `std::stable_partition` [is](http://eel.is/c++draft/alg.partitions#itemdecl:3):

> ```
> template<class BidirectionalIterator, class Predicate>
> BidirectionalIterator stable_partition(
>     BidirectionalIterator first, BidirectionalIterator last, Predicate pred);
> ```

<s>I didn't find the requirement that `BidirectionalIterator` should be a bidirectional iterator, but the name suggests so.</s> (See below)

**2.**
In the SGI STL, the specification [is](https://www.boost.org/sgi/stl/stable_partition.html):

> ```
> template <class ForwardIterator, class Predicate>
> ForwardIterator stable_partition(
>     ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last, Predicate pred);
> ```
>
> Requirements on types: `ForwardIterator` is a model of Forward Iterator.

The specification of complexity is the same for both, current standard and SGI, versions: at most `N log N` swaps, only `O(N)` swaps if there is enough extra memory and exactly `N` applications of the predicate and projection.

**3.**
The declaration in [libstdc++](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_algo.h#L1712) and [libc++](https://github.com/google/libcxx/blob/master/include/algorithm#L3245) looks like:

```
template<typename ForwardIterator, typename Predicate>
ForwardIterator stable_partition(
    ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last, Predicate pred);
```

In GCC and Clang `std::stable_partition` indeed works with forward iterators. For example:

```
int main() {
    std::forward_list<int> list{1, 4, 5, 2, 3, 0};
    std::stable_partition(list.begin(), list.end(), [](int i) { return i < 3;});

    for (auto v : list)
        std::cout << v << ' ';
}
```

[compiles and produces the correct output](https://godbolt.org/z/WJ9Yys). Microsoft's compiler fails to compile this code (no `--` operator). Intel's one succeeds.

I have two related questions:

- <s>Does `std::stable_partition` accepts at least bidirectional iterators by the standard or the name `BidirectionalIterator` is misleading?</s>
- If it indeed accepts only bidirectional iterators, why the support of forward iterators has been dropped?

**Edit**.

Found [this clause](http://eel.is/c++draft/algorithms.requirements#4.4):

> If an algorithm's template parameter is named `BidirectionalIterator`, `BidirectionalIterator1`, or `BidirectionalIterator2`, the template argument shall meet the `Cpp17BidirectionalIterator` requirements.

So, only the second question remains.

Comment: Maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21554635/how-is-stable-partition-an-adaptive-algorithm If it's a matter of implementation efficiency, `std::reverse` is also limited to bidirectional iterators.

Comment: @Bob__ Thanks for the link. But the choice between "slow" and "fast" versions discussed there is related to the availability of an additional memory buffer but not to the iterator category.

Comment: Sure, but the standard also mandates a certain complexity in terms of swaps. In the previous lines about `partition`, at  25.7.4.8 it says *"At most **N/2** swaps if the type of first meets the Cpp17BidirectionalIterator requirements for the overloads in namespace std or models bidirectional_­iterator for the overloads in namespace ranges, and at most **N** swaps otherwise."*. So *maybe* a bidirectional iterator is needed to ensure the [25.7.4.13](http://eel.is/c++draft/alg.partitions#13) requirements.

Comment: @Bob__ SGI STL that supports forward iterators has the same specification of complexity as the standard library that doesn't.

Comment: FWIW, even in C++98 it already required `BidirectionalIterator`: http://www.lirmm.fr/~ducour/Doc-objets/ISO+IEC+14882-1998.pdf

Answer (score 6):

First of all, no support has been dropped, `std::stable_partition` has always required `BidirectionalIterator` by the standard. Which does not mean that the implementors of the library are disallowed to give less restrictions on input arguments (if it continues to comply with other parts of the standard ofc). And so Gcc, Clang and Intel use their rights and made the code even more generic. You can think of it as a compiler extension of standard library.

Having said that one may ask why standard requires `BidirectionalIterator` here. I suppose it is possible because the authors of the standard didn't see a way to comply with the complexity requirements without this requirement. It is possible that the authors of gcc found a way to do it better than anticipated by the standard. Looking at the gcc source code kinda confirms this. https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_algo.h#L1613

EDIT:

I have dug through GCC library implementation and I think I get it. Implementation for `ForwardIterator`, `BidirectionalIterator` and `RandomAccessIterator` are different for `std::stable_partition`. This is due to different implementations of `std::rotate` which is used by the partitioning algorithm. And so, for forward iterator number of swaps is greater and can exceed `(last - first) * log(last - first)`.
Look [here](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_algo.h#L1307) and [here](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_algo.h#L1349).

Comment: `std::stable_partition` (and many other algorithms) came into the standard from the STL developed by Alexander Stepanov and his coworkers. GCC/libstdc++'s implementation of `std::stable_partition` follows that of SGI STL almost line by line (let alone identical file names - `stl_algo.h`). In STL, `std::stable_partition` accepted forward iterators with the **same** complexity requirements. That "authors of the standard didn't see a way to comply with the complexity requirements" is hardly possible given that Stepanov's STL was the basis of the standard library.

Comment: And if it indeed was the case, it looks like a bug that should be fixed. Probably I simply don't see a deep reason for this transition from forward iterators to bidirectional ones. Hence, the question.

Comment: @Evg I looked a bit more and I think I found it.

Comment: Implementations are different, but `std::rotate` has linear complexity for both forward and bidirectional iterators. The asymptotic number of swaps made by `stable_partition` should be the same for both iterator categories. A constant factor can change but that's not a good reason to ban forward iterators completely. For example, the number of swaps made by `partition` is different by a factor of 2 for forward and bidirectional iterators, but both are acceptable.

Comment: @Evg Notice that standard does not mention asymptotic complexity but exact maximum of swaps which would not be valild, while still being linear

Comment: I guess it should be considered as `O(N log N)` because log base is not specified. In contrast, e.g. [`std::binary_search`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/binary_search) specifies base explicitly (= 2). I don't know whether `std::stable_partition` can be implemented with exact upper bound `N log_2 N` on the number of swaps. Even if it can't, this is not a good reason to ban forward iterators completely.

Comment: @Evg current implementation for bidirectional iterator has max N log_2 N so I suppose it is possible. And for forward iterators it would not be the case. Still I agree with you that extending the standard and relaxing the requirements may be benificial

Comment: Also, `std::stable_partition` is not implemented solely in terms of `swap` operation. It also uses move assignments. So it is not clear what the exact bound `NlogN` even means.

Answer (score 5):

The problem seems to have historical and not mathematical reasons. Looking through Alexander Stepanov's [papers](http://stepanovpapers.com), I found this one: "[Partition and Related Functions](http://stepanovpapers.com/PAM3-partition_notes.pdf)".

It contains the following passage:

> *Remark:* It is interesting that this excellent algorithm is not in the C++ standard which requires *bidirectional iterators* for partition. I had known, implemented, and taught this algorithm for quite some time – since I first read about it in Bentley’s column in CACM in the mid-eighties. But my original STL proposal does, somehow, specify *bidirectional iterators* for both `partition` and `stable_partition`. Both of them were corrected in SGI STL, but most vendors are still behind. This little thing has been bothering me for over 10 years now; the most bothersome part being the fact of omission. How did it happen? I suspect that the explanation is quite simple: while in the early 90ties I already understood the idea of reducing every algorithms to its minimal requirements, and I also knew that the same operation could be implemented using better algorithms when we know more about the data to which they are applied, I was not yet fully aware of the need to provide an algorithm for the weakest case, if such an algorithm is available. It took several more years to understand the importance of “filling the algorithmic space.”

The following simple algorithm

```
template <typename I, // I models Forward Iterator
          typename N, // N models Integer
          typename P> // P models Unary Predicate
pair<I, I> stable_partition_inplace_n(I f, N n, P p)
{
    if (n == 0) return make_pair(f, f);
    if (n == 1) {
        I l = successor(f);
        if (p(*f)) l = f;
        return make_pair(f, l);
    }
    pair<I, I> i = stable_partition_inplace_n(f, n/2, p);
    pair<I, I> j = stable_partition_inplace_n(i.second, n – n/2, p);
    return make_pair(rotate(i.first, i.second, j.first), j.second);
}
```

is given in that paper. It works with forward iterators and performs `O(N log N)` swaps in the worst case.

Comment: No. It is mathematical. A bidirectional stable_partition can reduce the overhead of its work by testing the predicate at the beginning and incrementing the iterator if true. Similarly  it can test the the predicate at the end and decrementing the iterator if false. 
Providing care is taken not to evaluate any predicate twice, it is possible stable_partition never requires memory if the predicate pattern is TTTTT...FFFFF.
But forwardonly iterators can only advance at the beginning. So the memory overhead could be higher. The same issues show up with stable_sort & inplace_merge

Comment: @SJHowe You didn't get the point. The standard library doesn't provide `std::stable_partition` for forward iterators at all. It is not a question of efficiency, it's a question of existence.

Comment: I did get the point. In ISO C++1998, std:::sort did not guarantee worse case O(N * log N) complexity. SInce ISO C++2011, it now does. in ISO C++1998, std::partition had Bidirectional iterators at worst. In ISO C++ 2011, they can be Forward Iterators with different complexity for Forward compared to Bidirectional. I am saying they can be Forward for the algorithms named above, but if you do so, there may be greater memory costs.

Comment: @SJHowe But who cares about memory costs if that function doesn't even exist?

Comment: It can exist. If you were looking at the ISO C++ 98 standard, many functions like std::copy_if() were left out. std::partition has now changed and there are others.
In contrast std::reverse is almost impossible to do with Forward Iterators.
My point is these can be implemented in the standard.
In my lifetime I expect a version of the standard where intraselect is used in implementing std::nth_element which makes guaranteed O(N) performance rather than the weaker average O(N) performance.